# accessing child namespaced controllers from a parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

recently i came across problem problem in accessing the namespaced controllers i have a parent controller in `education/educations_controller.rb` as

```
class Education::EducationssController < ApplicationController
   def process_educations
     if highschool
       controller_to_redirect = 'highschool'
     if bacholors
       controller_to_redirect = 'bacholors'
     else
       controller_to_redirect = 'masters'
     end
    redirect_to :controller => controller_to_redirect, :action => 'process_educations'
   end
end
```

And three child controllers `education/highschool_controller.rb` , `education/bacholors_controller.rb` , `education/masters_controller.rb` with all the parametes present in `educations_controller.rb` passing to these controllers

```
class Education::HighschoolController < Education::EducationssController
   def proceed_educations
     do some process
   end
end


class Education::BacholorsController < Education::EducationssController
   def proceed_educations
     do some process
   end
end


class Education::MastersController < Education::EducationssController
   def proceed_educations
     do some process
   end
end
```

And respective views come after that but in this process the url becomes too long so i wanted to remove all the controllers from the url and then process so irrespective of anything user is taken  to same url, for this i changed `routes.rb` as

```
namespace :educations,:path => '' do
  scope "/educations" do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'educations#proceed_educations'
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'educations#proceed_educations'
  end
  resource :highschool ,:path => '' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'highschool#proceed_educations'
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'highschool#proceed_educations'
  end
  resource :bacholors ,:path => '' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'bacholors#proceed_educations'
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'bacholors#proceed_educations'
  end
  resource :masters ,:path => '' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'masters#proceed_educations'
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'masters#proceed_educations'
  end
end
```

This generated the same url for every controller but when i try to access them as in `educations_controller.rb` they always redirect to same controller `HighschoolController`.

I am not getting where i am doing things wrong, please help me understand this process, or if there is any better way of doing this then please suggest.

Comment: the url of `/educations/highschool` is too long? If so why not just make it `/highschool`? Maybe I don't understand your intentions but the problem is that you are defining the same endpoint for multiple routes (how exactly is it to know where to go?)

Comment: Also, it's going to the highschool route because that url is the first to match.  Rails gets the request, then scrolls through the routes file until it finds the first matching route (it doesn't continue to see if one may be even more tight-fitting).  In this case it finds highschool routes as a match.

Comment: then how can i hide controllers name from url and show all controllers action from same url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid making the same URLs for two namespaced controllers, it will be difficult for the rails to understand which controller to send which request.

However, what you can do is, in your `routes.rb`, you can eliminate showing controller names and can add space there for differentiation, like this:

```
namespace :educations,:path => '' do
  scope "/educations",:path => '' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'educations#proceed_educations',:path => ''
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'educations#proceed_educations',:path => ''
  end
  resource :highschool ,:path => '' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'highschool#proceed_educations'
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'highschool#proceed_educations'
  end
  resource :bacholors ,:path => ' ' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'bacholors#proceed_educations',:path => ''
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'bacholors#proceed_educations',:path => ''
  end
  resource :masters ,:path => '  ' do
   get 'proceed_educations',to:'masters#proceed_educations',:path => ''
   post 'proceed_educations',to:'masters#proceed_educations',:path => ''
  end
end
```

This way, the URL will be same but with extra spaces.